# Why is logisitic regression predicting TRUE values at a much higher rate than in the training data?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, prediction

I am trying to use logistic regression to make predictions in R.  I am confused as to why a model is predicting `TRUE` for 90% of predictions, when the training data had only a 50% probability of being `TRUE`.

Here is some test data:

```
set.seed(10)

x1 <- rnorm(10000, 0, 15)
x2 <- rnorm(10000, 10, 4)
x3 <- rnorm(10000, 3, 10)
x4 <- rnorm(10000, -8, 3)

b0 <- -4
b1 <- 2
b2 <- 15
b3 <- 90
b4 <- -23

e <- rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd=25)

y <- b0 + x1*b1 + x2*b2 + x3*b3 + x4*b4 + e
```

If I model `y` as continuous, the mean prediction is identical to the mean value of `y`.  For example:

```
cont_mod <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4)
cont_pred <- predict(cont_mod , data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4))

> mean(y)
[1] 602.8305
> mean(cont_pred)
[1] 602.8305
```

Thus, my intuition is that in a logistic regression the probability of the model predicting a `TRUE` value should be equal to the probability of a `TRUE` value in the training dataset.  However, when I use logistic regression to model `y` as a binary outcome `y_bin`, the model predicts `TRUE` values at a very high rate.

```
y_bin <- y < median(y)
bin_mod <- glm(y_bin ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4)

logodds <- predict(bin_mod, data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4))
odds <- exp(logodds)
prob <- odds / (1 + odds)

> mean(y_bin)
[1] 0.5
> mean(prob > 0.5)
[1] 0.896
```

After doing some searching here and on the internet, I found some people suggesting that a logistic regression model will make such predictions when it is fit/trained on unbalanced data.  But it is making these predictions even when I ensure that 50% of the values of `y_bin` are true!

So, why does logistic regression predict 90% of outcomes as `TRUE`, when only 50% of the training data had a `TRUE` outcome?  Additionally, if I should use a different value besides 0.5 as the cutoff between a `TRUE` and a `FALSE` prediction, how do I go about selecting the cutoff value?

Comment: `glm` does not fit a logistic regression unless you specify `family=binomial`.   Your  `glm` call is generating the same results as your `lm` call, due to the defaults for `glm`.  Furthermore, your call won't work as written, since `yb` isn't defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you would need to change your code to something like this:

```
set.seed(10)

x1 <- rnorm(10000, 0, 15)
x2 <- rnorm(10000, 10, 4)
x3 <- rnorm(10000, 3, 10)
x4 <- rnorm(10000, -8, 3)

b0 <- -4
b1 <- 2
b2 <- 15
b3 <- 90
b4 <- -23

e <- rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd=25)

y <- b0 + x1*b1 + x2*b2 + x3*b3 + x4*b4 + e

y_bin <- y < median(y)
bin_mod <- glm(y_bin ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, family = "binomial")
```

But this gives an error because numerical 0 and 1 occur. Your coefficients are very high which leads to perfect separation.

Change it to

```
b0 <- -4
b1 <- 2
b2 <- 3
b3 <- 4
b4 <- -2
```

and that error disappears.

and

```
head(bin_mod$fitted.values)
```

yields a wide range.

and

```
table(bin_mod$fitted.values > 0.5)
```

shows very close to a 50-50 split.

Comment: Getting fitted probabilities equal to 0 or 1 is not actually an "error". R simply issues a Warning message.